# Running mojolicious web app on Azure, linux containers

Tags: azure, docker, perl, azure-web-app-service, mojolicious

I'd like to test a simple mojolicious app on azure. But all I can get is a 'Application Error' when accessing the web app.

These are the steps I was following:

1. Create a new web app
2. Publish = Docker container
3. OS = Linux

On the Docker tab:

1. Options = Single container
2. Image src = Dockerhub
3. Access type = Public
4. Image/Tag = `scottw/alpine-perl` (I also tried with Image/Tag = `clearlinux/perl`)
5. Startup command: `sh -c "mojo generate lite_app /tmp/myapp.pl && morbo --listen 'http://*:80' /tmp/myapp.pl"`
6. Create a web app setting: WEBSITES_PORT = 80

This generates the following log:

```
2019-10-19 17:36:40.491 INFO  - Pulling image from Docker hub: scottw/alpine-perl
2019-10-19 17:36:40.959 INFO  - latest Pulling from scottw/alpine-perl
2019-10-19 17:36:40.960 INFO  -  Digest: sha256:9f732cddfc39af53c47709e0ce1b42a07fe3cfa18d48cbb6bee393e670494348
2019-10-19 17:36:40.960 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for scottw/alpine-perl:latest
2019-10-19 17:36:40.964 INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2019-10-19 17:36:41.006 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-10-19 17:36:41.007 INFO  - docker run -d -p 8559:80 --name testqqq2_0_2255c482 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=testqqq2 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=testqqq2.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8a04808bf31407f38566f64be531143f3be18392806dd1f91d6485b3824dbba3 scottw/alpine-perl sh -c "mojo generate lite_app /tmp/myapp.pl && morbo --listen 'http://*:80' /tmp/myapp.pl" 

2019-10-19 17:36:41.008 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-10-19 17:36:43.998 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container testqqq2_0_2255c482 for site testqqq2
2019-10-19 17:36:44.014 ERROR - Container testqqq2_0_2255c482 for site testqqq2 has exited, failing site start
2019-10-19 17:36:44.016 ERROR - Container testqqq2_0_2255c482 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
```

Following the advice from: https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/azure/app-service/containers/app-service-linux-intro#troubleshooting.

Gives me these logs:

```
/home/LogFiles>ls *
2019_10_19_RD0004FFDDD7F4_default_docker.log
2019_10_19_RD0004FFDDD7F4_docker.log
__lastCheckTime.txt

kudu:
deployment
trace

webssh:
pm2.err
pm2.log
/home/LogFiles>tail 2019_10_19_RD0004FFDDD7F4_default_docker.log
2019-10-19T17:28:19.004163856Z generate: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

2019-10-19T17:28:24.480791096Z generate: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

2019-10-19T17:36:43.167236229Z generate: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

2019-10-19T17:55:06.478078430Z generate: line 1: syntax error: unterminated quoted string

/home/LogFiles>tail 2019_10_19_RD0004FFDDD7F4_docker.log
2019-10-19 17:55:02.658 INFO  -  Status: Image is up to date for scottw/alpine-perl:latest
2019-10-19 17:55:02.688 INFO  - Pull Image successful, Time taken: 0 Minutes and 0 Seconds
2019-10-19 17:55:02.917 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-10-19 17:55:02.926 INFO  - docker run -d -p 58481:80 --name testqqq2_0_101834c8 -e WEBSITES_ENABLE_APP_SERVICE_STORAGE=false -e WEBSITES_PORT=80 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=testqqq2 -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_HOSTNAME=testqqq2.azurewebsites.net -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=8a04808bf31407f38566f64be531143f3be18392806dd1f91d6485b3824dbba3 scottw/alpine-perl sh -c "mojo generate lite_app /tmp/myapp.pl && morbo --listen 'http://*:80' /tmp/myapp.pl" 

2019-10-19 17:55:02.933 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-10-19 17:55:07.554 INFO  - Initiating warmup request to container testqqq2_0_101834c8 for site testqqq2
2019-10-19 17:55:07.624 ERROR - Container testqqq2_0_101834c8 for site testqqq2 has exited, failing site start
2019-10-19 17:55:07.642 ERROR - Container testqqq2_0_101834c8 didn't respond to HTTP pings on port: 80, failing site start. See container logs for debugging.
/home/LogFiles>
```

Could you please help me to see what I'm doing wrong?

**Edit**:

I'm adding the full log here:

https://pastebin.com/f05rSQq1

Please, note that at the beginning there were some unrelated error like this:

`2019-10-19 17:25:15.092 ERROR - Container start failed for testqqq2_0_aa3c3687 with System.AggregateException, One or more errors occurred. (Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"bash\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"}
) (Docker API responded with status code=BadRequest, response={"message":"OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused \"exec: \\\"bash\\\": executable file not found in $PATH\": unknown"}
)`

That was because at first I used `bash -c "..."` for the command. However the Alpine image does not include bash, but sh.

**Edit2**:
So the problem seems to be that the startup command box does not seem to like quotes. For example, `mojo daemon` works, but `bash -c "mojo daemon"` does not.

However, I'd like to use multiple commands for my start command, with `bash -c "whatever && whatever && ..."`.

Is there anything I could do?

Thank you.

Comment: `tail 2019_10_19_RD0004FFDDD7F4_default_docker.log` this only prints the last 10 lines of the log file. Could you show some more lines?

Comment: @HåkonHægland, Sure, I added the full log. Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, can you add the other log file also?

Comment: @HåkonHægland the other log file does not have more lines. Just those 4 "syntax error"

Comment: Ok, maybe the error is related to the startup command `mojo generate`? Since the error says *"generate: line 1: syntax error: ..."* . Can you try replace the startup command by something else like `sh -c "mojo --help"`? What errors do you get now?

Comment: I have news: the problem seems to be the quotes on the `bash -c "whatever"` startup command. If I use `mojo daemon` as a startup command, It works. However, `bash -c "mojo daemon"` does not. Also, single quotes don't work too. I believe that the command string is splitted by spaces: So something like `bash -c 'mojo daemon'` gets splitted into `bash`, `-c`, `'mojo`, `daemon'` and then de `daemon': -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching \`''` errors come up. Any idea how to use quotes or being able to use multiple commands?